# Checking if JTextField contains only specific allowed characters

Tags: java, regex, string, swing, jtextfield

I have a `JFormattedTextField` where I want only alphanumeric characters to be inserted. I am trying to use this code to launch a `JDialog` when the user types a non-allowed character, and in case everything is ok to get the string from the `JFormattedTextField`. When I run this code, no `JOptionPane` will come up when I type a symbol. I am aware that there is something wrong with my code, but due to my little experience I cannot identify it. I would appreciate some help.

Thank you in advance

```
static JFormattedTextField indivname = new JFormattedTextField();

final String individ = indivname.getText();

indivname.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        warn(individ);
    }
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        warn(individ);
    }
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        warn(individ);
    }       
    public void warn(String textcheck) {
        textcheck = indivname.getText();
        boolean match = textcheck.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]+"); 

        if (match=false) {                            
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have inserted restricted characters (Only alphanumeric characters are allowed)", "Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);                   
        }

        if (match=true) {                            
            textcheck = individ ;                     
        }                   
    }
});
```

Comment: `if (match = false)` <-- no! This will _assign value `false` to `match`_. You want `if (match == false)`

Comment: @fge I think it is false that it is true that the OP wants `match == false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the assignment operator `=` instead of the comparison `==` in lines with the `if` statements:

```
 if (match = false) {

 ...

 if (match=true) {
```

The expression `match = false` results in `match` getting a `false` value and the whole expression always returning `false`.

You should replace those with:

```
 if (!match) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have inserted restricted characters (Only alphanumeric characters are allowed)", "Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
 } else { // instead of if(match)
     textcheck = individ;
 }
```

which uses the value of `match` directly to determine what branch to execute.

Answer (score 2):

With `if (match=false)` you are assigning `false` value to `match`, and then `if` checks its value, and since it is `false` this block is skipped.

Same about `if(match=true)`.

Use

- `if(match==false)` or better to avoid mistakes with `==` use `if (!match)`
- `if(match==true)` or better `if(match)`.

Answer (score 1):

The point of using a JFormattedTextField is to edit the text as it is entered so that no invalid character can be added.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on How to Use [Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) for more information and examples. You probably want the section on `Mask Formatters`.